# PHP - character encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

Is it possible to convert **AoibhÃ­n** back to **Aoibhín** ?
If it is how can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the nature of such conversion? Typo or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is the result of some operation where there was a mix-up between ISO-8859-1 (or a similar encoding) and UTF-8.

If at all possible, try re-importing the data with the correct character set settings so the problem doesn't occur in the first place.

Other than that, it may be possible to get the data into the correct form by faking a character set, but to give any advice on that, you need to add details about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`iconv`](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), it converts from one character encoding to another.

Comment: `iconv` won't work, because the OP's example is already broken.